# How to show progress when using rake generate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll, octopress, jekyll-extensions

Is there any way to show the progress when I run `rake generate`? I have many posts, and when I generate the posts the progress seems to be locked.

I'm using Octopress.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify rake task and add support of progress-bar. Take a look at this gems https://github.com/ondrejbartas/rake-progressbar and https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar.

Also you can add `--trace` key so rake task will output steps being executed